# Get the last inserted row using JOIN statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, join

I am trying to create a simple issue-tracker using mysql and php. 
User can enter details in the `tracker` table and it will added to the `tracker` and the `statusmapping` table at once.

Later the user can change the 'status' which will then be added (not updated) to the `statusmapping` table.

I want to combine these two tables and get the output. When i get the output, i want to get the last inserted data from the `statusmapping` table for the given id.

My `tracker` table

```
+------------+---------+------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| tracker_id | tasksid | pagenameid | tracker_summary      | tracker_comment                                      | tracker_created_date |
+------------+---------+------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|         14 |       2 |          8 | some summary         | some comment to display for the buggy page.          | 2018-10-14 13:05:31  |
|         15 |       4 |          4 | revision for the faq | revision for the faq page and the comment goes here. | 2018-10-14 14:09:27  |
+------------+---------+------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

and `statusmapping` table. The second column `trackerid` is the `FK` for the `tracker` table.

```
+------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+----------------------+
| statusmapping_id | trackerid | statusid | statusmapping_date  | statusmapping_reason |
+------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+----------------------+
|                4 |        14 |        1 | 2018-10-14 13:05:31 | Newly opened!        |
|                5 |        14 |        2 | 2018-10-14 13:34:04 | This issue is closed |
|                6 |        15 |        1 | 2018-10-14 14:09:27 | Newly opened!        |
+------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

So far i tried this. I am getting `NULL` for the column `statusid`. But the last inserted id is `2` in the `statusmapping` table. How do i get that.

```
SELECT 
trk.tracker_id, 
trk.tracker_summary, trk.tracker_comment,
stm.statusid
FROM trackers trk
LEFT JOIN statusmapping stm ON trk.tracker_id = (SELECT MAX(trackerid) FROM `statusmapping`)
GROUP BY trk.tracker_id
```

This is the output.

```
+------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| tracker_id | tracker_summary      | tracker_comment                                      | statusid |
+------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|         14 | some summary         | some comment to display for the buggy page.          |     NULL |
|         15 | revision for the faq | revision for the faq page and the comment goes here. |        1 |
+------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In a separate [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), you can get the last update datetime for a `tracker_id`. Use that value to join to the main tables, to get the last entry for a `tracker_id`.

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
  trk.tracker_id, 
  trk.tracker_summary, 
  trk.tracker_comment,
  stm.statusid
FROM trackers trk
INNER JOIN statusmapping stm 
  ON trk.tracker_id = stm.trackerid 
INNER JOIN (SELECT trackerid, 
                  MAX(statusmapping_date) AS max_statusmapping_date 
           FROM statusmapping 
           GROUP BY trackerid) AS dt 
  ON dt.trackerid = trk.tracker_id AND 
     dt.max_statusmapping_date = stm.statusmapping_date
```

Comment: PK is `tracker_id` and FK is `trackerid` i updated your code on these and when run i get three rows.

Comment: @TheHive fixed now. changed column names